# How to get ArrayList<Integer> and Scanner to play nice?

Tags: java, casting, arraylist, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.*;

public class CyclicShiftApp{

   public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      while(scan.hasNextInt()){
         list.add(scan.nextInt());
      }
      Integer[] nums = new  Integer[list.size()];
      nums = list.toArray(nums);
      for(int i = 0;i < nums.length; i++){
      System.out.println(nums[i]);
      }   
}
```

Thanks to poor-mans-debugging I've found that the `while(scan.hasNextInt())` isnt actually adding anything. What might be going wrong? Is my google-fu weak or lack of know-how letting me down? I am rather new to programming, and so unfamiliar with Lists so thought this would be a nice first step but something isnt adding up. It also compiles fine so Its not syntax(anymore). Perhaps a casting issue?

Comment: You haven't told us anything about what input you've given it. It works for me. If I type in 10 (return) 20 (return) 30 (return) Ctrl-D (return) it shows the three numbers.

Comment: Oh sorry. Just a list of numbers with whitespaces. eg. 14 17 18 33 54 1 4 6

Comment: @SamwiseGibbens: Again, if I type that in, then hit return, then Ctrl-D, return, it prints out all the numbers. How are you terminating input? (Congrats for showing a short but complete program, and trying to learn from the ground up rather than racing straight to a GUI+database etc, by the way. I wish everyone took that approach.)

Comment: `14 17 18 33 54 1 4 6` it will treat as `String` input and `scan.hasNextInt()` will return false.

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder: No it won't. I've tried it - it works. (Given that Scanners *always* deal with text input, how would you expect nextInt to ever work?)

Comment: @Abi Isnt that the reason to use a List? So that if you dont know how many input entries there are, it will expand upon demand?

Comment: Input should be 14 <enter> 17 <enter> ... I think. And loop termination condition would any input other than int

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder: That works too, but so does just space separating them. Again, I've tried it, it works. Scanner.nextInt looks for the next *token*, and tokens are delimited by any whitespace by default.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes actually. Thanks for correcting me. :)

Comment: The problem is that `System.in` never "ends", i.e. EOF is never sent to the stream, so `hasNextInt()` after the last line is blocking waiting for more data.

Comment: @ExtremeCoders: You can make the loop end by providing any non-integer.

Comment: I am truly amazed at you guys. Honestly a little inspiring to see this response. You showed me how to enter my own data xD.

Comment: ask a stupid question, get a stupid answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work, master Samwise?

```
import java.util.*;

public class CyclicShiftApp{

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.print("Enter integers please ");
    System.out.println("(EOF or non-integer to terminate): ");

    while(scan.hasNextInt()){
         list.add(scan.nextInt());
    }

    Integer [] nums = list.toArray(new Integer[0]);
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
       System.out.println(nums[i]);
    }
  }   
}
```

I'm assuming there's a reason why you need the list as an array, otherwise the conversion to an array is unnecessary. As Jon Skeet mentions in the comments, the loop will terminate only when the stream doesn't have a next int, ie. a non-integer value or a file's EOF if you're using 'java CyclicShiftApp < input_file.txt'.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here :

```
 while(scan.hasNextInt()){  <-- This will loop untill you enter any non integer value
     list.add(scan.nextInt());
  }
```

You just have to enter a character say e.g `q` once you finished entering all the integer values and then your program will print expected results.

```
Sample Input :14 17 18 33 54 1 4 6 q
```

Comment: Is there a way to cut it off after it finds the last integer? I would think that hasNextInt fixed that? it seems like it should go.. 'if there is no next int, cancel loop'.

Comment: Yes, but for that you would have to terminate the input. Either with a file which ends automatically or something like Ctrl + C on Windows command line. (Or Ctrl + D and enter)

Comment: There is no way it can detect which is last int unless you define some. So use characters or non integer to specify that it is end of input.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;
class SimpleArrayList{
public static void main(String args[])
{
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList <Integer> al2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
System.out.println("enter the item in list");
while(sc.hasNextInt())
{
al2.add(sc.nextInt());
}
Iterator it1 = al2.iterator();
/*loop will be terminated when it will not get integer value */
     while(it1.hasNext())
{
 System.out.println(it1.next());
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the simple and easiest way to use Scanner and ArrayList together.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int num=sc.nextInt();
    ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>(num);
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
    list.add(sc.nextInt());

   }
    Iterator itr=list.iterator();
        {
       while(itr.hasNext())
       {
           System.out.print(itr.next()+" ");
        }
        }
    }
}
```