# How to store user input in a variable using a For Loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

I would like to know how to store user input using a variable when using a For Loop. When the user finishes the 5 question I want there to be a total at the end. The total of all the user inputs (user input). How would I do this using a variable?

```
import java.util.*;

public class mistakes {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i=1; i<6; i++){
            System.out.println("How many did participant " + i + " make on interface 1? ");

        }          
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't use the scanner at all. please try to solve the problem yourself then we might help you.

Comment: @PhilippSander how would I get user input without using a scanner?

Comment: don't get me wrong... you need a scanner. but you don't use it currently.

Comment: you have declared and instantiated the `Scanner` But in your code where do you use it?

Comment: I don't quite get it: you're able to declare variables like `input`  and `i`, use `i` at least but get stuck on another simple variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in :
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

And answered in:
[How to get ArrayList<Integer> and Scanner to play nice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098134/how-to-get-arraylistinteger-and-scanner-to-play-nice)

You must to add sc.nextInt(); for get the keyboard input. And declare a variable to store it, an arraylist for example:

```
Arraylist <Integer> inputs = new Arraylist <Integer> ();
```

After that store using scanner:

```
inputs.add(sc.nextInt());
```

Solution:

```
import java.util.*;

public class mistakes {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Arraylist <Integer> inputs = new Arraylist <Integer> ();

        for(int i=1; i<6; i++){
            System.out.println("How many did participant " + i + " make on interface 1? ");
            inputs.add(input.nextInt());
        }          
    }
}
```