# How to enter values in arraylist without asking the size of the array?

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to give input 4,5,6 to  the arraylist then next time i want to enter 83,2,4,5 without asking the size of the array from the user,using the scanner class.The input would be given at the run time.How could it be done with the help of arraylist.Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: This is ver basic stuff. You just add to the list. Internally, the list automatic resize the inner array for you

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Please provide some clear scenario, show what you tried so far (show your code!), and what your expected result is

Comment: I think he's talking about something like a scanner and inputting integers. `Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); String s = scan.nextLine(); List<Integer> ints = Arrays.stream(s.split(",")).map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());` is what immediately comes to mind. However, one should expand the mapping function to allow for error handling.

Answer (score 0):

this may help:

**Java ArrayList class uses a dynamic array for storing the elements**. It inherits AbstractList class and implements List interface.

The important points about Java ArrayList class are:

Java ArrayList class can contain duplicate elements.
Java ArrayList class maintains insertion order.
Java ArrayList class is non synchronized.
Java ArrayList allows random access because array works at the index basis.
In Java ArrayList class, manipulation is slow because a lot of shifting needs to be occurred if any element is removed from the array list.

Each ArrayList instance has a capacity. The capacity is the size of the array used to store the elements in the list. It is always at least as large as the list size. As elements are added to an ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically. The details of the growth policy are not specified beyond the fact that adding an element has constant amortized time cost.

An application can increase the capacity of an ArrayList instance before adding a large number of elements using the ensureCapacity operation. This may reduce the amount of incremental reallocation.

Comment: I know these things.But i have problem in implementing .i want to know how to take input from scanner class to array list without asking the size of an array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098134/how-to-get-arraylistinteger-and-scanner-to-play-nice?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa    this perhaps answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Basic exsample:

```
ArrayList<Integer> collection=new ArrayList<Integer>();

collection.add(83);
collection.add(2);
collection.add(4);
collection.add(5);
```

OR dynamically

```
boolean endContition=false;
while (!endContition){
int element= readElement(); /*retrive element to add in some way*/ 
collection.add(element); 
updateEndContition(); /*if someting happens swich endcondition*/
}
```

but pls try to be more specific when u ask!

Comment: You cannot make an `ArrayList<int>`

Comment: 'ArrayList<Integer>' is allowed 'ArrayList<int>' isn't allowed.

Comment: ups mistake, sry! Fixed!

Comment: Still won't compile. `new ArrayList<int>()` doesn't compile because the type parameter isn't the same as the type declaration. Although it's entirely unnecessary, due to the diamond operator `<>`. Unless you're using `var` in which case you need the type there.

Comment: agree! i forgot second parameters! this is so cheap XD 3yrs of programming go in crash after 7hours of work XD

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

When the user is entering his input line, create a `new ArrayList()`

Lets say `List list = new ArrayList();`

Now, for each item in the input call `list.add(/* user input here */);`